# The Euler-Poincare equation

Tags: mathematical-physics, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, group-theory, variational-calculus

Can anyone tell me very basically how the [Euler-Poincare equation](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Euler+Poincare+equation) generalises the [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)? Further does anyone know if there is an "easy" relationship between the two, i.e. can anyone derive either equation from the other? Finally I would be jolly grateful if anyone had a good BASIC source of information at an introductory level to the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The [stationary action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) and the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are very broad and general constructions. The field variables in the variational principle could in principle map into some generic [manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) $M$.
2. On the other hand, [Euler-Poincare (EP) equations](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Euler+Poincare+equation) appear in the special situation where the manifold is a Lie group $M=G$, and the action is left-$G$-
   invariant. One next uses the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map) to make the variables Lie algebra-valued (rather than Lie group-valued). The EP equations reads
   $$ \left( \frac{d}{dt}+ {\rm ad}^{\ast}_{\xi}\right) \frac{\delta \ell}{\delta\xi}~=~0, $$
   where the variables $\xi$ are Lie algebra-valued. The Lie algebra-valued EP equations are equivalent to the Lie group-valued EL equations for the same problem. See Ref. 1 for further details.
3. The [Euler (E) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_%28rigid_body_dynamics%29) for a rigid body are a special case of the EP equations.

References:

1. J.E. Marsden and T.S. Ratiu, *Intro to Mechanics and Symmetry,* 2nd Eds, 1998; Section 13.5.