# Variational form of Euler's incompressible fluid equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

I am trying to derive [Euler's incompressible fluid equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29) in terms of a variational stationary principle. Given Euler's flow equations:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = -\nabla p$$

$$\nabla\cdot v = 0$$

Starting with a Lagrangian consisting of the kinetic energy, and the continuity constraint (divergence free velocity):

$$\mathcal{L} = \int_\Omega{\frac{1}{2}|v|^2 - p(\nabla\cdot v)}$$

Can one simply apply the Euler-Lagrange equations:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{dt}}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial{v}} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial{{x}}} = 0$$

to arrive at the Euler equations? As far as I understand this is quite possible, but I am not sure exactly how to proceed. Specifically, how do you differentiate the divergence operator with respect to $v, x$?

I am hoping they can be derived from this simple form ($\mathcal{L} = T - V$), without invoking some of the more abstract, geometrical methods, e.g.: Arnold.

The closest I have seen is Luke's variational principle, but this is not as general. References welcome.

(Question moved from math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Um... You sure about that first equation? First, the units don't match, $L/T^2  = M/(T^2L^2)$(?).  Also, where did the advective term ($u \cdot \nabla u$) go?  Or is that something to do with the Lagrangian formulation?

Comment: @user3823992: I agree, the first equation should be written as $D_tv=-(\nabla p)/\rho$ where $D_t$ is the total derivative.

Comment: In general the Lagrangian ($L=T-V$) in Euler-Lagrange equations **need not** be a standard one (where the potential depends only on postion $x$). In many cases there are generalised potentials (i.e depending on velocity but in such a way that E-L equations hold with a generalised lagranagian $L=T-V_g$), example: lagrangian of Electromagnetism

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14652/2451

Answer (score 4):

Here we assume that OP is mostly interested in the [Eulerian fluid picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) (as opposed to the Lagrangian fluid picture). Both fluid pictures are discussed in great detail in Ref. 1.

Note however that in the methods of Ref. 1, the mass density $\rho$ is a dynamical variable. The variation of $\rho$ is important in order to obtain a full set of eoms. But OP specifically asks about [incompressible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow) fluids, which means constant $\rho$ (more precisely, along pathlines, cf. the continuity equation).

In [Luke's variational principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke%27s_variational_principle), which OP mentions, instead of varying $\rho$, one varies wrt. a free surface, which is insufficient to derive bulk eoms.

Alternatively, the [Euler fluid equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29) for constant $\rho$ can be viewed as as a special case of Euler-Poincare (EP) equations, which has a variational formulation, cf. Ref. 2-4 and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133958/2451) Phys.SE post. With a caveat. Because rather than deriving the sought-for equation

$$\frac{D(\rho u)}{Dt} ~=~ -\nabla p ,$$

one essentially only derives

$$\nabla \times  \frac{D(\rho u)}{Dt}~=~0, $$

i.e. the pressure $p$ does not enter into the variational principle.

References:

1. R. Salmon, *Hamiltonian Fluid Mechanics,* [Ann. Rev Fluid. Mech. (1988) 225](http://dx.doi.org/10.1146/annurev.fl.20.010188.001301). The [pdf file](http://www-pord.ucsd.edu/~rsalmon/salmon.1988.pdf) can be downloaded from the author's [webpage](http://www-pord.ucsd.edu/~rsalmon/papers.html).
2. V.A. Arnold and B.A. Khesin, *Topological Methods in Hydrodynamics,* 1998; $\S$7.
3. J.E. Marsden and T.S. Ratiu, *Intro to Mechanics and Symmetry,* 2nd Eds, 1998; Section 13.5.
4. Terence Tao, [*The Euler-Arnold equation*](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/the-euler-arnold-equation), blogpost 2010.