# Why do I get nonsense when trying to solve the Euler-Lagrange equations for a fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, classical-field-theory

Take an inviscid, incompressible fluid, ignore external forces for the sake of simplicity.

The Lagrangian density is

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{\rho}{2} {\vec v}\cdot \vec v
$$

I'm trying to solve Euler-Lagrange like so:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \vec v} = \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \vec v)} \right)
$$

The RHS is $0$ because $\mathcal{L}$ does not depend on any derivatives of $\vec v$.

The LHS is $\rho \vec v$.

This is nonsense, I was expecting to get the momentum equations for an inviscid incompressible fluid.

Comment: If you use position as your coordinate instead of velocity, you recover the continuity equation

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14652/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138149/226902. This paper contains a lot of references for the variational principle for the perfect fluid (and perfect multifluids) in special and general relativity https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03140

Comment: That's not at all what a Lagrangian for hydrodynamics would look like, though. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.06006 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09331 for examples of EFTs for hydrodynamics. They involve the density $\rho$ and momentum $\pi$ (whose thermodynamic conjugate is the velocity $v$).